# Finding a line through a keyword in a multiple line text file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling, file-location

(using Python 3.12.2)
I have a multiplelines file called "text.txt" and it has 3 lines, it goes like this:

line 1    -->    Hello, World!

line 2    -->    MrBeast is rich.

line 3    -->    :3 avg valorant player

However I would like to print only the line that has the "World" independent of the line it is located, which means I have to find the desired line first. I have been searching for a function that would do this for me and have come to the conclusion that there is maybe no such thing as `variable.lineindex("desired_string")` and will have to code it myself, any suggestions or am I being a moron?

Comment: question closed

Answer (score 1):

```
desired_string = "World"

with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        if desired_string in line:
            print(f"Found '{desired_string}' in line {line_number}: {line.strip()}")
```

You can break in if block if you need only the first occurence.

Comment: why is line_number an integer and line is a string? Is it becouse of the enumerate function or is it a build-in thing for the for loop?

Comment: It's because of how `enumerate` function works. Here's documentation https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/. It returns two `for` loop variables, first one is index of current element and second is current element.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you, thanks a lot for your help!! :D

Comment: @Carlos No problem. For sake of future readers, please consider upvoting and checking answer if it was satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each line and look for the line that contains your desired string like this:

```
filepath = "C:\\Users\\John Dee\\Desktop\\text.txt"
with open(filepath, 'r') as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        print(line if 'World' in line else '')
```

**NB:** If using relative file path, then do `filepath = text.txt`. If using an absolute file path, please note that the file path I used is for Windows.

Comment: so when i use the open() method, it will be treated as an object?

Comment: @Carlos yes it opens the file and returns it as a file object.